# Remove substring till first Token using regexp

Tags: regex, sed

I have  the Path:

**GarbageContainingSlashesAndDots/TOKEN/xyz/TOKEN/abc**

How coukt I remove GarbageContainingSlashesAndDots?
I know, it is before TOKEN, but Unfortunately, there are two substrings TOKEN in string.
using `sed s/.*TOKEN//` makes my string to **/abc**, 
but I need **/TOKEN/xyz/TOKEN/abc**
Thank You!!!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Divide and conquer:

```
$ echo 'Garbage.Containing/Slashes/And.Dots/TOKEN/xyz/TOKEN/abc' |
      sed -n 's|/TOKEN/|\n&|;s/.*\n//;p'
/TOKEN/xyz/TOKEN/abc
```

Comment: +1: Cool! Will remember this trick for that kind of problems. Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

Is perl instead of sed allowed?

```
perl -pe 's!.*?(?=/TOKEN)!!'


echo 'GarbageContainingSlashesAndDots/TOKEN/xyz/TOKEN/abc' | perl -pe 's!.*?(?=/TOKEN)!!'
# returns:
/TOKEN/xyz/TOKEN/abc
```

Sed does not support non-greedy matching. Perl does.

Comment: +1: Thank you! Good to know, it's called "non-greedy matching".

Answer (score 0):

```
echo "./a//...b/TOKEN/abc/TOKEN/xyz"|sed 's#.*\(/TOKEN/.*/TOKEN/.*\)#\1#'
```

Comment: Works for OP's example but not for general problem in the title "Remove substring till first Token using regexp" - you remove it till the before-last, not first Token.

Comment: @eumiro: *shrug* It's said there are "two substrings TOKEN in string".

Comment: +1: What a shame, I have not considered this :-) It would work in my particular case indeed! Thanks!

Comment: @Valentin Heinitz: That's what i've suspected before using the heavy artillery like emacs-batch:)))

Answer (score 0):

I think you have bash, so it can be a simple as

```
$ s="GarbageContainingSlashesAndDots/TOKEN/xyz/TOKEN/abc"
$ echo ${s#*/}
TOKEN/xyz/TOKEN/abc
```

or if you have Ruby(1.9+)

```
echo $s | ruby -e 'print gets.split("/",2)[-1]'
```

Comment: Unofrtunately I have a Windows environment. I wanted to minimize the usage of tools to basic cygwin/mingw tools.

Comment: You missed the fact that the "garbage" portion of the string contains slashes so neither of your techniques will work in this case.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for all suggestions, I've learnt something new.
Finally I was able to reach my goal using grep -o

```
echo "GarbageContainingSlashesAndDots/TOKEN/xyz/TOKEN/abc" | grep -o "/TOKEN/.*/TOKEN/.*"
```

Answer (score 0):

Using `grep`:

```
word='GarbageContainingSlashesAndDots/TOKEN/xyz/TOKEN/abc'
echo $word | grep -o '/.*'
```

Comment: You missed the fact that the "garbage" portion of the string contains slashes so neither of your techniques will work in this case.

Comment: You are right, that was a little space out on my part. It should be: `echo $word | grep -o '/TOKEN.*'`

Answer (score -1):

**UPDATE 2:** have you tried this?

```
s!.*\(/TOKEN.+TOKEN.*\)!\1!
```

**UPDATE:** sorry, non-greedy matches are not supported by sed

<strike>Try this:</strike>

```
s/.*?TOKEN//
```

`.*?` matches only for the first occurance of `TOKEN`.